# When I click on Refresh button on IE my javascript getting refresh -how to stop it

Tags: javascript

I developed a website using Javascript and HTML pages

Problem :

When i am clicking on refresh button on Internet Explore, it is going to home page instead of refreshing the current page of my web page. please do the need full

Regards
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are using ajax to update parts of the website after loading.

Ex: Say clicking on add button loads a form using ajax.

When you do like this the URL in the browser remains same even after loading the form. Because of this hitting the refresh button will not take you to form again.

Solution: 
Really Simple History (RSH) is lightweight JavaScript library for the management of bookmarking and browser history in Ajax/DHTML applications.

Use this library to update the browser URL after the ajax request. Now the refresh should work fine.

Hope this helps.